Adding whitespace before window.getSelection() removes it when new node is inserted in selection
I'm building a URL Link functionality to selected text in my app.

I select a text.
Click on Link button.
Enter URL in modal popup.
Click save.
I again click on Link button.
Update URL in modal popup.
Click save.

So far so good. I was able to create and update a URL to a selected text in my html. However this breaks when I add empty space or any character before selected text. For example,

I select the word "highlight" inside <div id="content">.
Click on Link button.
Enter URL.
Click on save button.
Now "highlight" word will have the css applied.
Now I place the cursor before "highlight" and add any one character or space.
Click on Link button.
Click on Save button.
This removes the one character or space I added before the word "highlight".
Now if I again repeat steps 6 - 9, its not happening. Its happening only for the first time not after that.

I'm not able to share the repro gif. so here is the repro video link - https://github.com/fingers10/NugetVulnerabilityCheck/assets/43729469/3eac8cfe-4d8a-4e7b-a8a8-64c6d0585638
Please can you assist on what I'm missing?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Text Highlighter</title>
<style>
.highlighted {
    color: blue;
}
#popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 9999;
}
#content {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content" contentEditable="plaintext-only">Select and highlight this text</div>
<button id="linkIcon">Link</button>

<!-- Popup -->
<div id="popup">
<input type="text" id="selectedText">
<input type="text" id="urlInput" placeholder="Enter URL">
<button id="saveBtn">Save</button>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
var linkIcon = document.getElementById("linkIcon");
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
var selectedText = document.getElementById("selectedText");
var urlInput = document.getElementById("urlInput");
var selectionRange; // To store selection range
var originalSelection = ""; // To store original selection
var lastAnchorText = "";
var lastUrl = "";
var textSelected = false;
var newNode = document.createElement("a");

// Function to get selected text
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return "";
}

// Function to check if an anchor element already exists in the selection range
function getExistingAnchor() {
    var nodes = selectionRange.cloneContents().childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeName === "A") {
            return nodes[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Function to check if there is an existing link in the content
function checkExistingLink() {
    if (!textSelected) {
        return false;
    }

    var anchor = getExistingAnchor();
    if (anchor) {
        var existingLink = anchor.href;
        if (existingLink !== "") {
            urlInput.value = existingLink;
            selectedText.value = anchor.innerText;
            popup.style.display = "block";
            originalSelection = anchor.innerText;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Event listener for link icon click
linkIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!checkExistingLink()) {
        var selection = getSelectedText();
        if (selection !== "") {
            selectionRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); // Store selection range
            originalSelection = selection; // Store original selection
            selectedText.value = selection;
            if (lastAnchorText !== "" && lastUrl !== "") {
                urlInput.value = lastUrl;
                selectedText.value = lastAnchorText;
            } else {
                urlInput.value = "https://";
            }
            popup.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            alert("Please select some text first.");
        }
    }
});

// Event listener for save button click
document.getElementById("saveBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var url = urlInput.value.trim();
    if (originalSelection !== "") {
        if (url !== "") {
            var existingAnchor = getExistingAnchor();
            if (existingAnchor) {
                existingAnchor.href = url;
                existingAnchor.innerText = originalSelection;
                newNode = existingAnchor;
            } else {
                newNode.href = url;
                newNode.innerText = originalSelection; // Use original selection
                newNode.classList.add("highlighted");
            }
            newNode.innerText = selectedText.value;
            selectionRange.deleteContents();
            selectionRange.insertNode(newNode);
            popup.style.display = "none";
            originalSelection = ""; // Reset original selection
            urlInput.value = "";
            lastAnchorText = originalSelection;
            lastUrl = url;
            textSelected = true;
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a URL.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("No text selected.");
    }
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>




I can't add text to the textbox in the modal. Anyway, HTML strips extra white-spacing from the content, so I think the issue you've described is rather native behavior. If you need to view multple white-space characters, you could set white-space: pre for the content element.

There are two inputs in modal popup. First input is readonly. The URL can be entered in second textbox. And I tried adding white-space: pre to content element and no luck..

Yes, why it's readonly if you expect it to be changed?

No we are not changing the display text from within popup... we will only be changing the URL within popup.. Did you get a chance to check the repro video I have added in the question?

Ah, OK. I'm on Firefox, it doesn't seem to support contentEditable="plaintext-only", got the snippet to work on Edge. There's a line var selection = getSelectedText().trim(); and several uses of innerText, which both are stripping leading/trailing white-space.

I tried removing trim and that doesnt resolve as well.. I suspect selectionRange.insertNode(newNode); making the issue..

After some debugging and tries, I was able to fix this by resetting the start offset of the range on click of link button as shown below.
let startOffset = contentDiv.innerText.indexOf(selectedText.value);
if (startOffset !== -1) {
    selectionRange?.setStart(contentDiv.firstChild, startOffset);   
}

Here is the complete working sample for my requirement.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Text Highlighter</title>
<style>
    .highlighted {
        color: blue;
    }
    #popup {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: white;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    #content {
        white-space: pre;
    }
</style>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content" contentEditable="plaintext-only">Select and highlight this text</div>
<button id="linkIcon">Link</button>

<!-- Popup -->
<div id="popup">
    <input type="text" id="selectedText">
    <input type="text" id="urlInput" placeholder="Enter URL">
    <button id="saveBtn">Save</button>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    var linkIcon = document.getElementById("linkIcon");
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    var selectedText = document.getElementById("selectedText");
    var urlInput = document.getElementById("urlInput");
    var selectionRange; // To store selection range
    var originalSelection = ""; // To store original selection
    var lastAnchorText = "";
    var lastUrl = "";
    var textSelected = false;
    var newNode = document.createElement("a");

    // Function to get selected text
    function getSelectedText() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            return window.getSelection().toString();
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            return document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Function to check if an anchor element already exists in the selection range
    function getExistingAnchor() {
        var nodes = selectionRange.cloneContents().childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].nodeName === "A") {
                return nodes[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Function to check if there is an existing link in the content
    function checkExistingLink() {
        if (!textSelected) {
            return false;
        }

        var anchor = getExistingAnchor();
        if (anchor) {
            var existingLink = anchor.href;
            if (existingLink !== "") {
                urlInput.value = existingLink;
                selectedText.value = anchor.innerText;
                popup.style.display = "block";
                originalSelection = anchor.innerText;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Event listener for link icon click
    linkIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let startOffset = contentDiv.innerText.indexOf(selectedText.value);
        if (startOffset !== -1) {
            selectionRange?.setStart(contentDiv.firstChild, startOffset);   
        }
        if (!checkExistingLink()) {
            var selection = getSelectedText();
            if (selection !== "") {
                selectionRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); // Store selection range
                originalSelection = selection; // Store original selection
                selectedText.value = selection;
                if (lastAnchorText !== "" && lastUrl !== "") {
                    urlInput.value = lastUrl;
                    selectedText.value = lastAnchorText;
                } else {
                    urlInput.value = "https://";
                }
                popup.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                alert("Please select some text first.");
            }
        }
    });

    // Event listener for save button click
    document.getElementById("saveBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var url = urlInput.value.trim();
        if (originalSelection !== "") {
            if (url !== "") {
                var existingAnchor = getExistingAnchor();
                if (existingAnchor) {
                    existingAnchor.href = url;
                    existingAnchor.innerText = originalSelection;
                    newNode = existingAnchor;
                } else {
                    newNode.href = url;
                    newNode.innerText = originalSelection; // Use original selection
                    newNode.classList.add("highlighted");
                }
                newNode.innerText = selectedText.value;
                selectionRange.deleteContents();
                selectionRange.insertNode(newNode);
                popup.style.display = "none";
                originalSelection = ""; // Reset original selection
                urlInput.value = "";
                lastAnchorText = originalSelection;
                lastUrl = url;
                textSelected = true;
            } else {
                alert("Please enter a URL.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("No text selected.");
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>



